# Работа с программами через php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть сервер на windows, там установлен php и на нем работает сайт.
На сервер я установил программу Nitro Pro 9, для конвертации файлов doc в pdf.

Вопрос, можно ли организовать логику на php, то есть создать такой инструмент который бы запустил через php процесс конвертации файла в программе Nitro Pro 9 которая установлена на этом же сервере.

Буду благодарен за информацию.

Comment: Если эта ваша Nitro Pro умеет работать принимая все параметры через командную строку - можно.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов а есть какие-то примеры, что можно прочитать

Comment: Документацию на shell_exec можно почитать, например...

Comment: Судя по документации к программе - она не поддерживает командную строку.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу командной строки к windows-приложениям - там все очень печально, поскольку они графические в 99,99% случаев. Даже если командная строка приложения имеет параметры, запускать исполняемый файл с параметрами и слушать ответ удовольствие ниже плинтуса

Если задача в том, чтобы конвертировать DOC в PDF, имея php на Windows, то посмотрите вот на этот сервис: https://convertio.co/ru/api/docs/

Судя по всему, сервис работает, позволяет обращаться к себе через CURL, имеет интерфейс на PHP на GitHub. Я бы посоветовал вам его использовать, или не его, а аналогичные

Подобных сервисов много, это первый в поисковой выдаче, который мне попался. **Не отправляйте конфиденциальную и важную информацию в подобные сервисы**. Пожалуйста.

Если же DOC является результатом чего-либо, и у вас есть исходный материал этого чего-то, посмотрите в сторону https://tcpdf.org/ Отличная библиотека, умеет генерировать PDF из кода или из HTML